# PDFs are auto publishing erroneously

Tags: sdl-tridion

PDF Files are auto publishing without adding to the auto publisher list. Pages and Components are working fine. I'm new to SDL Tridion and I don't understand where to start to find out the issue.

Comment: Hi Seshu, welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. To fully help you, can you please explain your issue in detail with screenshots, exceptions, and what is expected vs current behavior :)

Comment: I have recently joined in my current company and  I have check with manager about the screenshots. I will update the full details after he confirms me.

Thank You so much for responding Marko

Comment: sure, you can hide all relevant info about the client, as all we do, you don't event need to use exact names of publications etc... We just need more detailed description of system so that we can help you. This is because, you will soon find out, that you can achieve same result in at least 5 ways in tridion :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you mean the standard Publishing Queue, an "auto publisher list" would likely be a customization specific to your company. I've seen this based on item attributes such as:

- Type of item (e.g. content based on a specific Schema)
- Metadata in the item or its containing folder
- Location (specific folder or Bundle)
- Maybe naming convention

Comparing things like this could help you see why your PDF files are behaving differently than Components and Pages (again, more info will help and they don't have to be screenshots).

Otherwise PDF files are typically Multimedia Components that are either:

- Published indirectly when a Page or Component is published (based on template)
- Published explicitly, where users can choose the PDF to publish.

So if you have a Page or Component that references a binary, the binary (PDF) might publish automatically depending on the template behavior. Use the **Where Used** feature to see if this might be the case.

It's a good idea to ask a colleague or check with your developers or IT for help.